# Host An application in google app engine to work on particular time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-appengine-node

I want to host an application in the google engine, the purpose of my application is to get data from a different server once in a day. So  I don't want my application to work full time in day(As it is costlier). I just want to run the application for an hour in a day and pay only on that basis. Is it possible to do it in that way?

Comment: Hi @MariyaJames, Google App Engine offers an amount of each resource for free for your applications. If these free quoates are exceeded, then you will be charged. Check [App Engine Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas) for more info. Since you want to create a task at a particular time a day, you may want to take a look at [Cloud Schedulers](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules). Scheduler tasks work along with Google App Engine, as shown [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-app-engine-cron-job-monitoring-bbf5c2ed6ca3).

Comment: If this does not apply to you, then you can check out [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/), which is a service that allows you to pay only for the resources you use, and you can [create and configure cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) to work along. I hope all this info is helpful, and keep me posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depend of your needs. App Engine **standard** has 28H free per day of F1 instance type, and 9H of B1 instance type (depend of your scaling type).

App Engine **flexible** doesn't have free quota -> This is expensive for some hours per days.

If App Engine standard matches your need, take care of the timeout. Each request can last more than 60 secondes. You can use [Cloud Task](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/) to defer background task. By the way, a task can last up to 24h.

If App Engine standard doesn't match, because of language limitation, third party library/binary limitation and you need to have a container and that's why you need to run on App Engine Flexible, you can consider [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs). However, the request are limited to 15 minutes and you have a generous free tier.

So, provide more inputs if you want more advice.

Comment: Could you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638095/call-google-endpoint-frameworks-from-node-js-application/58643103?noredirect=1#comment103615881_58643103