# Call google endpoint frameworks from node.js application

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I need to call API's created using google cloud endpoint framework from my node.js applications. How I will be able to complete auth process and call the above APIs? Is it possible from node.js application to access the API's?

Comment: Where is your node.js application deployed?

Comment: It is in the aws instance,.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks#limitations), Cloud Endpoints Framework is a web framework for the App Engine standard (only) Python 2.7 and Java 8 runtime environments. It doesn’t support Node.js (nor PHP, Go) runtime environments.

=========================================================================

EDIT:

The answer to your initial question (“Is it possible from node.js application to access the API's”) is yes.

Your client application does not need to be in Python or Java, it can be on any language such as Node.js.

Regarding authentication, for the backend app (GAE), the flow would be the following:

1. You can authenticate the access to the Endpoints by [creating a Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/service-account-authentication) on Google Cloud Platform.
2. In the [API Decorator](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/decorators-reference#defining_the_api_endpointsapi), add the Service Account and public cert link.
3. In the API Decorator, add the SA as audience also.

[image]

Finally, on your Node.js application (client side), request Authentication by requesting the JWT token:

1.Create a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) with the same audience set before on the API Decorator and sign it with the service account's private key.

2.Send the signed JWT in a request to the API.

Below you have some examples of the call request. I didn’t find examples in Node.js, they are in Python, but you can translate them to Node.js since the flow is basically the same:

[1.JWT Authentication request GCP official documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request)

[2.Accessing an API requiring Authentication (Python Client)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/access_from_python#accessing_an_api_requiring_authentication)

[3.Github Google-Client-JWT Sample.](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/endpoints/getting-started/clients/google-jwt-client.py)

Comment: The app which has these endpoints is already in the app engine and written in python. I want to call those endpoints from another application which is a node.js, and hosted in aws.  So do you mean, I can access those api's from other application, only if the client application is also in Python or Java right?

Comment: Please confirm.

Comment: I apologize for misunderstanding  your question. I have edited my initial answer.

Comment: but how to load the API's that we created on the endpoints? Couldn't be able to find any npm packages for gapi which supports it.  All the current packages support google default set of api's (like calendar, sheet etc).

Comment: If you are trying to use Cloud Endpoints Framework for App Engine, you can use Java or Python, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks). Endpoints Frameworks doesn't support Node.js runtime.